# Why can't I override existing :after and :before pseudo-elements?

Tags: html, css

I have two same CSS rules but one is not overwriting the other.

I used **right** instead of **left** rule, but not it does not overwrite the **left** rule. Other hand **top** rule is overwriting. I have also used the **!important** rule but it does not make any changes.

Is there any way to make the change?

example URL:https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdGSM.png

```
.navigation-bar-wrapper:after, .navigation-bar-wrapper:before {
   top: -10px;
   right: 58px;
}

.navigation-bar-wrapper:after, .navigation-bar-wrapper:before {
   top: -10px;
   left: 14px; 
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Why would you expect left to overwrite right? They are two separate properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Important: Don't use `!important`.

When you need to reset a CSS rule that is set by another stylesheet use `initial` with a slightly stronger selector. If the CSS you are adding is loaded later than the one you're overwriting, use the same exact selector.

```
div.navigation-bar-wrapper:after,
div.navigation-bar-wrapper:before {
    top: -10px;
    left: initial;
    right: 22px;
}
```